# Handling errors/exceptions in spring cloud data flow streams

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

One of the components in our stream is throwing heap out of memory error, when input file is larger than a certain limit. While we are working to fix this issue, I would like to know, if such errors can be caught so that we can log or send notification accordingly.

I have seen couple of examples for error handling using imperative approach. I would like to know how error handling at application level can be achieved through an error channel using functional approach and log the error info. Please also provide links if any to resources on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error handling available is provided by Spring Cloud Stream as described in the [Error Handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling) section of the reference guide.

There is not a mechanism built-in to Dataflow to detect and react to errors in an executing stream.

Comment: the documentation linked above is for imperative function as mentioned in the first section : "... anything you read later in this section with regard to Retry Template, dropping failed messages, retrying, DLQ and configuration properties that assist with all of it only applies to Message handlers (i.e., imperative functions)."